# Return a specific line of pascals triangle recursivly with python

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

The code that I'm writing should have outputs as follows:

```
>>> pascalLine(0)
[1]
>>> pascalLine(1)
[1, 1]
>>> pascalLine(2)
[1, 2, 1]
>>> pascalLine(3)
[1, 3, 3, 1]
```

I have the code doing this through iteration, but I need it done recursively, and I'm lost in trying to do so. Here's the code that I have:

```
def pascalLine(n):
    value = 1
    new_row = [value]
    if n == 0:
        return new_row
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            value = int((value * (n-i)) / (i+1))
            new_row.append(value)
        return new_row
```

Any help welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
from operator import add

def pascal_line(n):
    if n < 2:
        return [1]*(n+1)
    l = pascal_line(n-1)
    return [1] + map(add, l[1:], l[:-1]) + [1]
```

Comment: This works! Kind of embarrassed by the simplicity of this now that I see this... Thanks!

Comment: Also, just a minor a side note, I think it'd be syntactically correct too to add an else for the last two line.

Comment: No, the first two `return` statements leave the function immediately so the `else` statement is superfluous